# what is foo in int **foo[][]()

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, declaration

I am currently studying for my C-Midterm and I encountered this declaration:

```
int **foo[][]()
```

When looking for the solution as to what this declaration means my tutors actually gave two different answers:
1) foo is an array of arrays of functions with return type pointer to pointer to an int
2) foo is an array of arrays of pointers to pointers to a function with return type int
I know the "start with the name of the variable, continue to the right until you reach the end or ')' then go back to your last starting point and continue to the left until you reach the start or '('" rule so I think 1) is the correct answer here but I am not entirely sure.

Thanks, 
Ozelotl

Comment: http://cdecl.org Though there are too few many unknown dimensions.

Comment: Per [cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+**foo\[\]\[\]()](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=int+**foo[][]%28%29): "array of array of function returning pointer to pointer to int".

Comment: BTW: Why didn't you just *test it*, by using it in a program?

Answer (score 1):

It is nothing specific. Meaning that on the surface it looks like a C declaration, but it is not well-formed. It is illegal and as such it means nothing.

Firstly, it appears like a two-dimensional array declaration, but in C language an array declaration is required to specify all sizes except possibly for the very first one. Your declaration omits the second size as well, which makes it illegal.

Secondly, even if we ignore the missing sizes, it looks like a declaration for an array of functions. It is illegal to declare arrays of functions in C.

For example, this would make a legal C declaration

```
int (**foo[][42])()
```

but not what you have originally.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of this declaration is that `foo[][]` declares a 2-D array (or it would, if the second bound had a dimension specified - as it stands that's illegal); and then the rest of it is:

```
int **bar();    // with bar = foo[][]
```

which is a function taking unspecified arguments and returning `int **`. However, since `bar` is an array type here this attempts to declare an array of functions, which is illegal. (Not to be confused with an array of function pointers, which would be OK).

The grammar rules are that the `**` bind to the `int` (not to the `bar`) unless you use parentheses to force them to bind to the `bar`; so they are part of the type `int **` and they are not saying that `bar` is a pointer.